# Connect to 2 databases from same model in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that run in 2 different countries. Lets say US and Brazil.
I have a User Model that connects to US or Brazil depending on a param passed by calling:

`User.establish_connection("Brazil_DB")
 User.establish_connection("US_DB")`

The problem I am facing is that if a US user comes in the middle of a session from a Brazil user ActiveRecord Drops my Brazil Connection and connects to the US DB.

Is there any way to manage such situations in ActiveRecord?

Comment: Firstly why are these managed separately in this day and age I don't think we need to segregate nationalities :). Second if this must be the case why not create 2 models and then modularize there consistencies and include the module in the classes? This way you can set separate connections for each class and then keep all the similar logic in the module.

Comment: @engineersmnky, that is what i ended up doing. I was thinking if there was an easier way to do it, but i found out there is no easy way

Answer (score 1):

You really should have one database with a nationality flag on your relevant tables, or two different applications deployed in different datacentres. This kind of thing *will* be an enormous hassle.

ActiveRecord can handle having different tables in different databases, but it's not capable of understanding how to handle one table living in several at the same time. You need an extension to manage this.

The problem becomes serious when you do things like:

```
 Model.find(params[:id])
```

Which connection should you use for that? Unless you have additional context the answer is "I don't know."

It really sounds like you should deploy two instances of your application each with a different `database.yml` file.

Comment: I ended up adding separate models for the second DB. this way the models will use different DB connection and not mess with each other. I thought there would be an easy way but I think there is no easier way then having separate models. Thanks @tadman

Comment: Separate models is also an acceptable solution here, though I would re-visit why you need separate databases and make sure that's the right call.

Comment: Yeah, that has been done long time ago and requires lots of effort to merge the two.